# Turn the selectInput label into a choice that is displayed by default and cannot be selected

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below with a `selectInput()`. I was wondering if I could turn the `label` "Variable" into a choice which will be displayed by default instead of "Cylinders" while "Cylindes" will still be the `selected` choice. Of course the `label` will not be displayed.It would be like:
[image]

```
#app.r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(

    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                  c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                    "Transmission" = "am",
                    "Gears" = "gear"),
                  selected = "Cylinders")
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Comment: What should the behavior be? If the user click on the ```selectInput```, the choices are "Cylinders", "Gears" and "Transmission" but not "Variable"? Or is it something else?

Comment: the variable should be like "greyed out" or something. It will still be the label but inside the selectinput not inside it.I basically want to save space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `shinyjs` package, I determine whether the mouse is on the `selectInput` or not and adapt the content of `selectInput` with this condition.

First of all, I define a vector of choices. This is necessary since we need to update this vector whether the mouse is on the input or leaves the input, and I don't know another way of listing the possible values of an input.

Then, I define two events:

- if the mouse is on the input, and if "Variable" is in the list of choices of the input (`choices_input`), then I update `selectInput` to remove "Variable" from this list of choices.
- if the mouse leaves the input, and if "Variable" is not in the list of choices, I do the contrary.

Additionally, in the second event, you need to add an `if` statement to fix the value of `selectInput` to the choice you made, even after the mouse leaves.

Full code:

```
#app.r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

choices_input <- c("Variable",
                   "Cylinders" = "cyl",
                   "Transmission" = "am",
                   "Gears" = "gear")

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    useShinyjs(),
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      selectInput("variable", "",
                  choices = choices_input,
                  selected = "Variable")
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) { 

    onevent("mouseenter", "variable",
            if ("Variable" %in% choices_input) {
              updateSelectInput(
                session = session,
                inputId = "variable",
                choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                            "Transmission" = "am",
                            "Gears" = "gear"),
                selected = input$variable)

              choices_input <<- c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                  "Transmission" = "am",
                                  "Gears" = "gear")
            })

    onevent("mouseleave", "variable", {
            if (!("Variable" %in% choices_input)) {
              updateSelectInput(
                session = session,
                inputId = "variable",
                choices = c("Variable",
                            "Cylinders" = "cyl",
                            "Transmission" = "am",
                            "Gears" = "gear"),
                selected = "Variable")

              choices_input <<- c("Variable",
                                  "Cylinders" = "cyl",
                                  "Transmission" = "am",
                                  "Gears" = "gear")
            }
            if(input$variable != "Variable"){
              updateSelectInput(
                session = session,
                inputId = "variable",
                choices = c("Variable",
                            "Cylinders" = "cyl",
                            "Transmission" = "am",
                            "Gears" = "gear"),
                selected = input$variable)
            }
      })

  }
)
```

Note: apparently, the mouse is considered to be "on the input" if it is just above the input, where the label (nothing in this case) should be. I don't know how to fix it for now.

Note 2: surely, you can fill the blank space when the mouse is on `selectInput` the first time by displaying a message (i.e adding another choice in `choice_input`) and by nesting an `onclick()` event (same package) in `onevent()` (to remove this message/choice if you click on the input).

Comment: great approach tnx